# Child Component Not Binding in React

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, modal-dialog, bind

I have the following problem. I have a child component called `Modal` that is composed of a bootstrap button and a popup. The `Modal` appears inside a render component called `renderPosts`.

Component.js

```
  deleteThis(id){
    console.log("THE ID IS", id);
  }

  renderPosts(post) {
    return (
      <tr key={post.id}>
    
          <td className="col-md-3"> {post.id}</td>
          <td onClick = {this.deleteThis.bind(this, post.id)}>CLICK HERE</td>
          <td>
            <Modal 
                modalId="deletepost"
                className="btn btn-danger"
                onClick={this.deleteThis.bind(this,post.id)} />
          </td>

      </tr>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-12">
            <div>
              <table className='table table-striped header-fixed'>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th> Test </th>
                    <th> Delete </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   {this.props.post.map(this.renderPosts.bind(this))}
                </tbody>
              </table> 
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {  post:state.post.all};
}
```

When my modal is like below, it WORKS fine. I'm able to output each different id via the onClick method attached to the prop called `deleteThis`:

```
import React from 'react';

const Modal = ({onClick, modalId, className}) => {
    return (
        <div>
        <button 
          type="button" 
          data-dismiss="modal"
          className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-right" 
          onClick={onClick}>
         DELETE
        </button>
       </div>
             
    );  
}

export default Modal;
```

Here is where I am stuck. I want to use the Pop up Modal feature in Bootstrap. The code below allows for me to get the pop up feature. But my problem is, when I click the button, the onClick method shows an id of `1` all the time.

Modal.js (bootstrap button with Modal)

```
import React from 'react';

const Modal = ({onClick, modalId, classNameNameName}) => {
    return (
        <div>

        <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

        <div id="myModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={onClick.bind(this)}>Show Id</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
             
    );  
}

export default Modal;
```

I think the reason why the id is always `1` for the code above is because the button with the onClick method is inside the Modal which only pops up if you click the other button.

Is there any way I can bind the id to the onClick handler in the code above?

I'm thinking I'll need to do something like:

```
  onClick={this.deleteThis.bind((this,feed.id).bind(this))} />
```

But I don't know how to translate that into working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here, `Modal` is defined as a functional stateless component

```
const Modal = ({onClick, modalId, classNameNameName}) => {
    // ...
```

A functional component doesn't has the keyword `this`.

But that wasn't the problem, the **real problem** was all your Modal elements were having same id `myModal` in the html and you are getting the same event triggered when you are clicking on the other element.

So here is a working fiddle in which I assigned **dynamically generated Ids** for Modals.

https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/2ub6rmkc/

Comment: i decided to use a react friendly modal library but this worked as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `this` variable will always refer to the current instance of the component. But you can't bind to a pure (i.e. functional) component. Nor should you. Just use `onClick={onClick}` as you have done for the first Modal.

I think your real problem is that you're trying to use Bootstrap, which is a jQuery based framework, in React. Try [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) instead.